# What does it mean by "There is no primary key for this table, it may contain duplicates."?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I know there is no unique column or columns in this table.
But, does this mean there are more than one row with exactly same columns? OR does it only mean that some columns can have duplicate values but no exactly same rows in the table?
Also, I use with cte as (select distinct (column1, column2...)" all the time to remove duplicate rows from these tables before joining other tables with primary keys...I feel like it may not be necessary but I am not sure. Could someone clarify this for me? Thanks!

I have this question because of this problem:

```
Table: Prices

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| product_id    | int     |
| start_date    | date    |
| end_date      | date    |
| price         | int     |
+---------------+---------+
(product_id, start_date, end_date) is the primary key for this table.
Each row of this table indicates the price of the product_id in the period from start_date to end_date.
For each product_id there will be no two overlapping periods. That means there will be no two intersecting periods for the same product_id.
 

Table: UnitsSold

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| product_id    | int     |
| purchase_date | date    |
| units         | int     |
+---------------+---------+
There is no primary key for this table, it may contain duplicates.
Each row of this table indicates the date, units, and product_id of each product sold. 
 

Write an SQL query to find the average selling price for each product. average_price should be rounded to 2 decimal places.

Return the result table in any order.
```

For the answer, I write

```
select p.product_id, round(sum(units*price)/sum(units),2) as average_price
from prices p
join unitssold u on p.product_id = u.product_id and purchase_date between start_date and end_date group by p.product_id;
```

The submission is successful. But I wonder if the answer is still correct if there are duplicate rows in the unitssold table...As duplicate rows are calculated too, right?
[screenshot of the leetcode problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gjze.png)

Comment: If you don't have a primary key, you can have two or more rows exactly the same. The way for removing duplicates it depends on the data you have and what you are doing. You can avoid duplicates using unique keys, or you can delete duplicates or you can use distinct to get different values in a column/row. It is really wide

Comment: PRIMARY KEY presence guarantees only PK expression value uniqueness. If there is no PK but UNIQUE KEY exists then it guarantees UK expression value uniqueness except the rows where this expression value is NULL. Non-unique index (and indices presence) guarantees nothing.

Comment: DId the answer help

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your case, if you don't have a unique key (or primary key) on **product_id** then there can be more than row with the same **product_id**.  The database engine will not check stop this from happening.

If you do have a **unique key** of **product_id** then the database will raise an error when to try to insert a row with a **product_id** if one such row already exists.